# mysql to mysqli conversion error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

this is my code was in mysql now i want to change as mysqli but getting an error.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as totalCount FROM blog_posts";
        $rec = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
        $total = $rec['totalCount'];
```

what I did

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as totalCount FROM blog_posts";
        $rec = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link,$query));
        $total = $rec['totalCount'];
```

but the error i am getting that

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\html\function.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\html\function.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\wamp\www\html\function.php on line 6
```

dBconfig

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","blogdemo");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

?>
```

Comment: Have you defined `$link` as the connection? Can you show that part of the code?

Comment: According to the first error message, `$link` is `null`.  That would cascade to the rest of the errors.  Define `$link`.

Comment: $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","blogdemo");
 here it is @David

Comment: But where in the script, @IamSrkfan? It needs to be visible from the file where you run the query.

Comment: added @Qirel sir.

Comment: No need for the "sir" :-) But did you include `dBconfig` to the file where you run the query..?

Comment: yes , i did @Qirel

Comment: @IamSrkfan If you included the **dBconfig** then why it is telling `Undefined variable: link` on the line number 6 ? check out this line `Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\wamp\www\html\function.php on line 6`

Comment: Can you show the code where you do that..? Because, clearly `$link` is undefined, else PHP wouldn't throw a fuzz about it :-)